# Processing multiple values string in Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a questionnaire dataset in which one of the columns (a question) has multiple possible answers. The data for that column is a sting of a list, with multiple possible values from none up to five i.e `'[1]'` or `'[1, 2, 3, 5]'`

I am trying to process that column to access the values independently as follows:

```
def f(x):
        if notnull(x):
            p = re.compile( '[\[\]\'\s]' )
            places = p.sub( '', x ).split( ',' )
            place_tally = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0, '5':0}
            for place in places:
                place_tally[place] += 1
            return place_tally

df['places'] = df.where_buy.map(f)
```

This creates a new column in my dataframe "places" with a dict from the values i.e: `{'1': 1, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 0}` or `{'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0}`

Now what is the most efficient/succinct way to extract that data form the new column? I've tried iterating through the DataFrame with no good results i.e

```
    for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
         r = row['places']
         if r is not None:
             df.ix[row_index]['large_super'] = r['1']
             df.ix[row_index]['small_super'] = r['2']
```

This does not seem to be working.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add code to generate a frame similar to the one you are using, or show such a frame and rephrase your question using the example frame?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are intending to do?

```
for i in range(1,6):
    df['super_'+str(i)] = df['place'].map(lambda x: x.count(str(i)) )
```